# Frontal Detection of sst & Chlorophyll image

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, modis

I am working on sea surface temperature satellite images and looking for delineating gradients in open source on the basis of temperature. Is there any tool like Cayula and Cornillon front detection tool of ArcGIS [`[1]`](http://code.env.duke.edu/projects/mget/export/HEAD/MGET/Trunk/PythonPackage/dist/TracOnlineDocumentation/Documentation/ArcGISReference/CayulaCornillonEdgeDetection.DetectEdgesInBinaryRaster.html) that may help in this.

The one method that is suggested to me is to use high pass filter and contouring. But in both the cases I am not able to draw a line on a temperature specific front. In high pass filter it is detecting all the edge which I am not interested in and in contours it is interval based.

I'm searching for a  tool in QGIS (or any open source) that automatically:

- identifies gradients(fronts) based on temperature,
- draw the line and
- generates shapefile.

Per a commentor's request: the Cayula Cornillon front detection tool automatically detects SST fronts from satellite SST data. The original paper is published here:

> [Cayula, J. F., & Cornillon, P. (1992). Edge detection algorithm for
>    SST images. Journal of Atmospheric and Oceanic Technology, 9(1), 67-80.](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0426(1992)009%3C0067%3AEDAFSI%3E2.0.CO%3B2)

Here's an example dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rtxhln299szonb1/may25.csv?dl=0

Comment: Cayula and Cornillon are both terms that appear to be new to GIS SE.  Would you be able to edit your question to describe what they are or to include links to descriptions of them, please?

Comment: Can you provide a subset of said SST data for testing?

Comment: Can you re-provide the smaple data? The link seems not valid anymore...

Comment: According to [this](http://www.ioccg.org/handbook/casestudy16_miller.pdf) document by Peter Miller, the MGET (Marine Geospatial Ecology Tools) version of Cayula and Cornillon front detection can also be run from Python.  It is not clear just from his comment whether arcpy is necessary, but it might be worth checking on.  It also states 'If you are a Python expert and plan to use MGET without ArcGIS, you can ignore the steps relating to ArcGIS. For help with installation, please contact us.' on the MGET installation page.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer based on @Cotton.Rockwood comment :*

> According to [this document by Peter Miller](http://www.ioccg.org/handbook/casestudy16_miller.pdf), the MGET (Marine
>   Geospatial Ecology Tools) version of Cayula and Cornillon front
>   detection can also be run from Python. It is not clear just from his
>   comment whether arcpy is necessary, but it might be worth checking on.
>   It also states 'If you are a Python expert and plan to use MGET
>   without ArcGIS, you can ignore the steps relating to ArcGIS. For help
>   with installation, please contact us.' on the MGET installation page.